# Rails 3.1 querying the database encrypted with attr_encrypted gem (where clause on encrypted columns)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have encrypted a field in the table using the `attr_encrypted` gem. Now I want to query on that particular column, comparing it with a value I am retrieving from a form. How can I do this?

**EDIT**: I need to query on a number of encrypted columns. Eg: searching on `encrypted_email`, `encrypted_name` etc. (using OR condition in `where` clause)

Answer (score 3):

`attr_encrypted` intercepts `find_by` methods, so you should be able to do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_encrypted :email, :key => 'a secret key'
  attr_encrypted :password, :key => 'some other secret key'
end

User.find_by_email_and_password('test@example.com', 'testing')
```

This is rewritten as

```
User.find_by_encrypted_email_and_encrypted_password('ENCRYPTED EMAIL', 'ENCRYPTED PASSWORD')
```

Comment: What if I want to say that I want to find by email or age or name and all 3 are encrypted?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [dynamic finders](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) in ActiveRecord?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with it but I have not used it for the "or" condition. I guess it can be used for "and" only. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think you are correct. In that case you could do it client-side. Pull 1 record with each query and pick first of them.

Comment: That will result in too many db calls. Right now I am loading the whole table in memory and manipulating the data. I want something more efficient !!

Comment: @AramBhusal: keep trying then :-)

Comment: @AramBhusal you can use User.encrypt_email(email) to manually encrypt a value. Then you can use the encrypted value in your custom query containing "OR"

Comment: Sean Huber's suggestion doesn't work if you use the :per_attribute_iv_and_salt mode, because `User.encrypt_email(email)` will return different encrypted values even for the same email string, due to using different IV and Salt values.

Answer (score 2):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_encrypted :email, :key => 'a secret key'
end
```

If you want to write a query to retrieve user whose email is 'abc@xyz.com' then you can do either

```
User.where(encrypted_email: User.encrypt_email('abc@xyz.com'))
```

or

```
User.scoped_by_email('abc@xyz.com') # works only for dynamic scope methods
```

Comment: Does searching using the where scope with the `encrypt_email` attribute method work if you're doing `per_attribute_iv_and_salt` mode?

Comment: @richsinn I have not tried that way. But you can give a shot :)